# how to get current state of a ksqldb table?

Tags: ksqldb

After reading some article I have understood that ksqdb table is actually an aggregated stream. meaning its show current state of business.Not history of business.History of business contains stream.But when I use push query in table then it showing history list not current state. My process is defined below.

**stream create:**

```
CREATE STREAM products2 (product_name VARCHAR KEY, cost DOUBLE)
WITH (kafka_topic='products2', partitions=1, value_format='json');
```

**table create:**

```
CREATE TABLE products2_t (product_name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, cost DOUBLE)
WITH (kafka_topic='products2', partitions=1, value_format='json');
```

**insert query:**

```
insert into PRODUCTS2 (product_name, cost) values ('a', 1); 
insert into PRODUCTS2 (product_name, cost) values ('a', 2);
insert into PRODUCTS2 (product_name, cost) values ('b', 1);
insert into PRODUCTS2 (product_name, cost) values ('b', 2);
```

**stream output :** that is ok

`select * from products2  emit changes;`

[image]

**table output:** that is not ok according to ksqldb table definition : 
[image]

Expecting output list will be:

```
a 13 
b 5
```

So please help me. where is wrong here. 
**Thanks to all.**

Answer (score 1):

The table will show the current state, but with `EMIT CHANGES` (i.e. a push query) you're receiving output when that state *changes*.  If you re-run that query when the input is paused, you'll see just the current state.

If you want to query the current state not subsequent changes, you can run a pull query, for which you need to materialise the state in your table. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS_T AS
SELECT PRODUCT_NAME, LATEST_BY_OFFSET(COST) AS LATEST_COST
FROM PRODUCTS2
GROUP BY PRODUCT_NAME;
```

Now you can query it directly - and notice that the query returns and does not wait for any future state changes:

```sql
ksql> SELECT LATEST_COST FROM PRODUCTS_T WHERE PRODUCT_NAME='a';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|LATEST_COST                                                                                                                                                                            |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2.0                                                                                                                                                                                    |
Query terminated
ksql>
```

Comment: thank you so much sir for your answer. but i have one issue when i re-run  ( select * from products2_T  emit changes;) after pushed data then ii showing same data like history list not showing current state list  like a - 13 and b - 5. otherwise how can i get latest item list at a time by pull query not one by one with where condition.